# Mean and standard deviation of red channel of multiple images

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I want to calculate the mean and standard deviation of red channel of multiple images in matlab.

Here is my code so far:

```matlab
imagesPath = imageSet('path');

n = size(imagesPath.ImageLocation,2)

sum = zeros(512,512);

for i=1 : n

    I = imread(imagesPath.ImageLocation{i});
    I = imresize(I, [512 512]); 
    I = double(I);
    I = rgb2gray(I);
    sum = sum + I;
end

   m = sum. /n;
```

Comment: There is no question. What's your problem with your code?

Answer (score 0):

see

https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imread.html

```
A = imread('ngc6543a.jpg');
//imread returns a 650-by-600-by-3 array, A.
```

the image is in RGB, meaning that we have 650-by-600 pixels of red, then green and then blue colors. To average over the red, simply do

```
mean_red_X = mean(A(:, :, 1), 1);
```

(to illustrate what is happening, I'm taking the mean twice, once for the x- and once for the y-dimension)

To get the standard deviation, do the same with std, but be aware that the second argument does **not** specify the dimension to take the standard deviation of (i.e. not analog to mean). If you want to take the standard deviation over both dimensions, maybe linearize the matrix first.

```
all_red_A = A(:, :, 1);
all_red_A = all_red_A(:);
std_red   = std(all_red_A);
```

Answer (score 0):

@Dr.J is right, but I believe there is a typo in the response. It should be:

`mean_red_X2 = mean(mean(A(:, :, 1),1),2);`

This computes the mean in y, and then x direction.

However, you can also use `mean2`, which computes the mean of the entire n-dimensional array passed :

`mean_red_X = mean2(A(:, :, 1));`